# Is it possible to maintain the order of json string using JSON.serialize?

Tags: rest-api, integration, json, post, serialization

I have a simple json format that I am trying to practice for the complex format that I am going to make. But it seems like, I'm not able to maintain the order when using the JSON.serialize method because of the Map that I am referencing inside of the inner class.  Is there another way to maintain the order of the JSON that I will be sending out to external API?

Sample json:

```
{
   "name": "Apple MacBook Pro 16",
   "data": {
      "year": 2019,
      "price": 1849.99,
      "CPU model": "Intel Core i9",
      "Hard disk size": "1 TB"
   }
}
```

This is the sample code:

```
  public class ApexCallout {         
    public static void met() {
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://api.restful-api.dev/objects');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        
        //String x = '{"name": "Apple MacBook Pro 16","data": {"year": 2019,"price": 1849.99,"CPU model": "Intel Core i9","Hard disk size": "1 TB"}}';
        //String jsonString = JSON.serialize(x);  

        Map<String, Object> jsonObj = new Map<String, Object> {
            'name' => 'Apple MacBook Pro 16',
                'data' => new Map<String, Object> {
                    'year' => 2019,
                        'price' => 1849.99,
                        'CPU Model' => 'Intel Core i9',
                        'Hard disk size' => '1 TB'
                }
        };
            
        ApexCallout.innerClass innerCl = new ApexCallout.innerClass();
        Map<String, Object> mp = new Map<String, Object>();
        mp.put('year', 2019);
        mp.put('price', 1849.99);
        mp.put('CPU Model', 'Intel Core i9');
        mp.put('Hard disk size', '1 TB');
        
        innerCl.name = 'Apple MacBook Pro 16';      
        innerCl.data = mp;
            
        String myJSON = JSON.serializePretty(innerCl);
        System.debug('myJSON: ' + myJSON);
        
        request.setBody(myJSON);
        
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

        // If the request is successful, parse the JSON response.
        System.debug(response.getBody() + '' + response.getStatusCode());
       
    }
    
    public class innerClass {
        public String name;
        public Map<String, Object> data;
        
    }          
}
```

Comment: As an aside, JSON objects generally don't require properties in a specific order. Check the documentation to see if this applies to you.

Comment: Is there an instance where the JSON will not maintain the order?

Comment: I believe the original order is never maintained by the standard Salesforce mechanisms (unless the fields happen to already be ordered the same way).